# CS0119 NULL exception & CS1526 a new expresstion required error on foreach loop

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-4

I am getting error "Invalid Operation Exception" and "A new expression required"
"list" variable. can any one help to check what is wrong in my code.

Error shows null exception on foreach loop. for further help i am attaching error message picture for better understanding.

```
        gomalEntities1 db = new gomalEntities1();

        var query = (
            from m2 in db.invoices
            join m in db.paymentDetails on m2.id equals m.inv_Id
            join m3 in db.loadings on m2.fk_loading equals m3.id
            join m4 in db.destinations on m2.fk_destination equals m4.id
            join m5 in db.vehicle_owner on m2.fk_vehicle equals m5.id
            join m6 in db.products on m2.p_Id equals m6.id
            orderby m.adv descending
            where m2.id == sesstionId select new {
                m2.tripDate,
                m2.invoiceNo,
                m6.productName,
                m4.destination1,
                m2.freight,
                m.inv_Id,
                m3.loading1,
                m2.shortage_amount,
                m2.shortage_Qty,
                m5.name,
                m5.vehicle,
                m5.mobile,
                m5.capacity,
                amount = (m.adv == true ? m.amount : 0)
            });

        var list = query.GroupBy(x => x.inv_Id).Select(y => y.FirstOrDefault());
        foreach (var r in list)
        { 
            data.Add(new reportClass {
                tripDate = r.tripDate != null ? r.tripDate.Value.ToString("D"): "",
                InvoiceNo = r.invoiceNo != null ? r.invoiceNo.ToString(): "",
                ProductNo = r.productName != null ? r.productName.ToString(): "",
                Destination = r.destination1 != null ? r.destination1.ToString(): "",
                Freight = r.freight != null ? r.freight.ToString(): "",
                Loading = r.loading1 != null ? r.loading1.ToString(): "",
                ShortAmount = r.shortage_amount != null ? r.shortage_amount.ToString(): "",
                ShortQty = r.shortage_Qty != null ? r.shortage_Qty.ToString(): "",
                TripAdvance = r.amount != null ? r.amount.ToString(): ""
            });
            totalFreight += r.freight;
            t_shortageAmount += r.shortage_amount;
            t_tripAdv += r.amount;
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Is that error occurs in `foreach (var r in list)` (obscured by message in attached image)? Have you tried `query.GroupBy(x => x.inv_Id).FirstOrDefault();`?

Comment: yes this error occurs in foreach (var r in list) and yes i also tried (x=> x.inv_Id).FirstOrDefault()); but same error occured

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto sorry  query.GroupBy(x => x.inv_Id).FirstOrDefault(); code works but GroupBy not working

Comment: Have `GroupBy` results same as `query` results (by applying `ToList()` method directly after `query`)? If the `query` compiles, it returns `IQueryable` which should be materalized to `ICollection` before using `foreach`.

Comment: if i am using this code query.GroupBy(x => x.inv_Id).FirstOrDefault(); result same as query result by applying Tolist() method. can you elaborate your further message